# React Styled Component слайдер в слайдере Swiper js

Tags: reactjs, swiper, styled-components

На странице 2 слайдера.
Первый отвечает за пролистывание периода (например, 1987-1991, 1992- 1995, 1996 - 2000 и т д), второй - за пролистывание событий в периоде по каждому году (например, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91). Получается, слайдер в слайдере. [image: слайдер]

Стили для внутреннего и внешнего прописаны как разные компоненты и выглядят по типу:

```
const EventList = styled(Swiper)`
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: start;
`;

const EventItem = styled(SwiperSlide)`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 20px;
width: 320px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
`;
```

По идее это должны быть разные слайдеры, как если бы у них были разные классы

Кнопки реализованы как два разных компонента по типу кода ниже, соответственно они тоже должны работать отдельно друг от друга:

```
function SlideButtons() {
  const swiper = useSwiper();

  return (
    <BtnWrapper>
      <EventContainerBtn onClick={() => swiper.slidePrev()}>
        <BtnImg src={PrevIcon}/>
      </EventContainerBtn>
      <EventContainerBtn onClick={() => swiper.slideNext()}>
        <BtnImg src={NextIcon}/>
      </EventContainerBtn>
    </BtnWrapper>
    
  )
}
```

Внешние кнопки отрабатывают норм, внутренние отрабатывают как внешние, хотя должны пролистывать только год, а не целый период

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Предположу что оба компонента завернуты в один провайдер. то есть хук 'useSwiper' один и тот же для всех дочерних компонентов. просто заверни в два разных провайдера (из доков это вроде <Swiper>{children}</Swiper>)

Comment: либо всплытие событий происходит: добавь e.preventDefault() в onClick.